# How to solve this exception: "X references an unknown entity: Y"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is my code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class GenericData {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String url;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @ManyToOne
    private Set<GenericData> inbounds = new HashSet<GenericData>();

    @OneToMany
    private Set<GenericData> outbounds = new HashSet<GenericData>();

    // Getters, setters and rest of class ...

} // End of class
```

- A generic data can have 0 or more `ìnbounds` from other generic data.
- A generic data can have 0 or more `outbounds` to other generic data.

When I run this code, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne 
           on my.domain.Video.inbounds references an unknown entity: java.util.Set
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `@ManyToOne` should store one thing. Use:

```
@ManyToOne
private GenericData inbounds;
```